# Is there any PostCSS plugins for sum variables?

Tags: css, postcss

I just using `precss` plugin now, but i want to calculate variables in PostCSS like this

```
$sidebar-width: 50px;
$container-padding-left: 20px;

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: $sidebar-width;
  z-index: 100;
}
#container {
  margin-left: -$sidebar-width;
  padding-left: $sidebar-width + $container-padding-left;
}
```

Is there any plugins for calculate `+` in postCSS?

I also tried `calc($sidebar-width + $container-padding-left);` but it doesn't work.

I looked up for https://github.com/postcss/postcss/blob/master/docs/plugins.md
but I couldn't find that I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found `postcss-calc` https://github.com/postcss/postcss-calc

This was what I wanted. plugged calc module after `precss` makes it.

Answer (score 2):

> padding-left: $sidebar-width + $container-padding-left;

postcss-automath does it better, without calc()

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you put variables plugin after a postcss-calc. Just use PreCSS plugin pack, when order is correct.